# Modal box with sliding animation in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a simple modal dialog box as shown in the code below, which I will use to add help at certain points of a web form.

I would like to add a sliding animation effect that causes the dialog to slide into the screen when the modal is opening, and slide back out when the modal is closed:

[image]

I can't find a solution for what I want to achieve. My modal code currently looks like this:

```js
function openModal(mod_name){
  var modal = document.getElementById(mod_name);
  modal.style.display = "block";
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
function closeModal(mod_name){
  var modal = document.getElementById(mod_name);
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<style>
  body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: red; }
  .modal { display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1; padding-top: 100px; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); }
  .modal-content { margin: auto; padding: 20px; width: 80%; }
  .close { color: #323232; float: right; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; }
  .close:hover, .close:focus { color: #424242; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<button id="oModal" onclick="openModal('myModal1')">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal modal_move">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button id="cModal" class="close" onclick="closeModal('myModal1')">&times;</button>
    <p>Some text in the Modal...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this : https://jsbin.com/qecajijuni/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach might be to use the CSS3 `transition` and `transform` rules to achieve the required slide in/out animation effect for your modal.

One approach would be to add CSS rules to `modal` to define default transition and transform behavior, along with an `open` modifier class that defines the `transform` of the modal when it's visible:

```
/* Updated CSS with open selector */
.modal.open {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.modal {
  /* Update CSS with transition and transform rules */
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Next, you would replace the inline style changes of the `display` rule, with logic to toggle the `open` class on your `modal` element like so:

```
// Add open class to toggle "open" mode
modal.classList.add('open');

// Remove open class to "hide" modal
modal.classList.remove('open');
```

These two idea can be combined with you existing code as follows:

```js
function openModal(mod_name) {
  var modal = document.getElementById(mod_name);

  // Add open class to make visible and trigger animation
  modal.classList.add('open');
}

function closeModal(mod_name) {
  var modal = document.getElementById(mod_name);
  // Remove open class to hide and trigger animation
  modal.classList.remove('open');
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: red;
}


/* Updated CSS with open selector */

.modal.open {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.modal {
  /* Update CSS with transition and transform rules */
  transition: transform 1s linear;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #323232;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #424242;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<button id="oModal" onclick="openModal('myModal1')">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal modal_move">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button id="cModal" class="close" onclick="closeModal('myModal1')">&times;</button>
    <p>Some text in the Modal...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wooww ! Really cool :). Thank you very much. I would like to understand, the `.modal.open` is made to specify the transition when opening?

Comment: You're welcome! The main idea behind `.modal.open` is that it has "greater specificity" - that basically means that the `transform` rule for `.modal.open` overrides the `transform` rule for just `.modal` on it's own. When the `open` "modifier" class is applied to the `classList` of the `modal` element, that causes the `.modal.open` transformation to become active, and at that point, the `transition` defined on `.modal` kicks into gear, and animates the modal. Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use translate transform for this:

I changed your code like this: https://jsbin.com/qecajijuni/2/edit?html,js,output

```
 <style>
  body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: red; }
  .modal { transition: 1s transform;transform:translate(500px); position:absolute; display: block; position: fixed; z-index: 1; padding-top: 100px; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); }
  .modal-content { margin: auto; padding: 20px; width: 80%; }
  .close { color: #323232; float: right; font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; }
  .close:hover, .close:focus { color: #424242; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
<h2>Modal Example</h2>
<button id="oModal" onclick="openModal('myModal1')">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal modal_move">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <button id="cModal" class="close" onclick="closeModal('myModal1')">&times;</button>
    <p>Some text in the Modal...</p>
  </div>
</div>


function openModal(mod_name){
  var modal = document.getElementById(mod_name);
  modal.style.transform = "translate(0)";

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
  modal.style.transform = "translate(500px)";
    }
  }
}
function closeModal(mod_name){
  var modal = document.getElementById(mod_name);
  modal.style.transform = "translate(500px)";
}
```

Comment: No worries. Glad to help.